# wxPython "Library not loaded"

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I made a wxPython app for Mac and packaged it with py2app. Two people have already said they can't get it to launch, with the following error message:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/username/Desktop/MCManager.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.6/wx/_core_.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Desktop/MCManager.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.6/wx/_core_.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I have only been able to test the app on Mac 10.6.7. Both of the people having the problem are using 10.7.x. Has anyone else had this issue, or know what it means? It seems from the message that it's trying unsuccessfully to load the wx library, but the wx library should be in the app
s Resources folder, correct?

Here's my setup file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import py2app
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    options = dict(
        py2app = dict(
            iconfile = 'MCManager.icns',
            packages = 'wx',
            site_packages = True,
            plist = dict(
                CFBundleName = "MCManager",
                CFBundleShortVersionString = "1.2.2",
                CFBundleGetInfoString = "MCManager 1.2.2",
                CFBundleExecutable = "MCManager",
                CFBundleIdentifier = "net.sourceforge.mcmanager",
            ),
        ),
    ),
    app = ['ScriptUnix.py']
)
```

I run it with `arch -i386 python26 filename.py py2app`, (`arch` because I can't get Python to run 32-bit without `arch`, and 2.6 because, very very long story short, I can't use 2.7 with py2app).

Comment: Is python26 the stock Python 2.6 that came with OS X? If so, have you read the documentation on semi-standalone builds for py2app, or the basic tutorial? Because that's probably your problem.

Comment: Meanwhile, why can't you use 2.7 with `py2app`? Is there something wrong with your 2.7 setup?

Comment: @abarnert http://pastebin.com/vsv2ggGz . I was allowed to install python 2.7.3, but I can't install py2app fot it.

Comment: But you can install `py2app` for the system python 2.6? That's bizarre. Have you considered installing things into your home directory instead of system-wide? You don't need an admin password for that, and nearly all Unix software is designed to work that way—including Python, which lets you set up a per-user site-packages. Or, better, a virtualenv environment. At any rate, if you can't install py2app for a non-Apple-installed Python, you cannot generate standalone packages without a whole lot of work, so there is no solution to your problem.

Comment: @abarnert it's installed by default for 2.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're building a semi-standalone app. As [the docs](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html) explain in various places, if you're using a "vendor Python", meaning any of the Python versions that came pre-installed with OS X, `py2app` cannot build a standalone app. For example:

> If the --semi-standalone option or a vendor Python is used, then the Python.framework is ignored. All other vendor files (those in /usr/ or /System/ excluding /usr/local/) are also excluded.

So, it does not package up the `wx` libraries in `/usr/lib`, because those are vendor libraries. Instead, it just links to the existing ones. There are no such libraries on a standard OS X 10.7 system. Even if there were, the fact that you end up explicitly linking to the 2.8.0 version from 10.6 means it probably wouldn't work on later systems.

What you need to do is to get those `wx` libraries copied into your `.app` bundle, and reference them from there. And `py2app` will not do that for you if you run it with your vendor Python. Which means you have three choices:

1. Use a separate Python installation.
2. Trick `py2app` into building a standalone app anyway, possibly by hacking up the `py2app` sources.
3. Bundle the app yourself (or use a different tool).

The best answer is usually #1. In your comments, you say that you were able to install Python 2.7.3 (presumably from python.org?), and you were able to install `py2app` for the vendor 2.6, but that you weren't able to install `py2app` for the custom 2.7.3. That sounds highly implausible. (If you were able to install 2.7.3 somehow, it should be installed into directories that you have access to.) But, even if it's true, it doesn't matter; you can install Python packages into a user-specific site-packages directory, under your home directory. You don't need admin rights for that. And in fact, most Unix software is designed to work that way.

An even easier way to do that is to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). Yes, I know, you can't install it, but you don't have to. If you read the docs, there's even a whole set of instructions on how to bootstrap a virtualenv on a system where you can't install anything. The result is your own personal Python installation, based on the system 2.7.3, but that you have total control over. So you can install `py2app` there. (There are a few notes about using `py2app` and `virtualenv` together, which you should read about in the `py2app` docs.)

If you can't or won't do any of those things, then `py2app` can't do what you want, at least not out of the box. But it's open source. And there are even comments in the source explaining why it doesn't try to make standalone builds from system Python. And most of the really tricky stuff is separated out into separate packages (like `macholib` and `altgraph`), so you should be able to understand `py2app` itself, well enough to hack together a standalone package that works for your specific app. (That's a lot easier than modifying `p2app` to fix the underlying problem in a fully general way.)

Or you could look at other tools that do similar things as py2app. Try searching PyPI for [py2app](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=py2app) or [freeze](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=freeze) and see what comes up. You can generally install packages into your home directory, or run them without installing them, so start playing with whatever looks promising and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with my setup file, arguments, and other info. I have a fresh install of wxPython (but I don't know about the actual wx C++ library), and many other users on OSX run it with no problem.

Comment: That still isn't enough information; you have to answer all the questions, not just some of them. But I can guess: You're probably releasing a semi-standalone build, which will happen to work with anyone who has perfectly compatible versions of Python, wx, and anything else, and not work for anyone else. Which probably means everyone with 10.6.x or later, but not 10.5, 10.7+, or earlier 10.6.

Comment: I basically did answer everything. How can I make it fully standalone?

Comment: No you didn't answer everything. Is it the stock `python26` (in `/usr/bin` and/or `/System/Library/…`) or not? The short version is, `py2app` cannot automatically create fully-standalone builds out of system Python installations. So you either have to learn the details of how `py2app` works, or install a different Python, ideally the stock python.org distribution, and use that to `py2app`.

Comment: I believe it's the stock 2.6, the only Python modifications I have made are installing 2.7.3, and reinstalling wxPython 2.8 (because I thought it was outdated)

Comment: How did you install wxPython 2.8—and apparently install it over top of an Apple installation—if you can't install anything on your machine?

Comment: the incompetent administrators allowed me to install 2.7 and wxPython 2.8, but py2app is "a virus".

Comment: @tkbx: Wow… What if you download the py2app tarball and rename it to "An Educational History of Maine's Bureaucracies"? :) Anyway, I think your best option here is to set up a per-user site-packages in your home directory or, better, a virtualenv, around 2.7. This should be easier than any of the alternatives that don't require tricking administrators.

Comment: @tkbx: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv is "a tool to create isolated Python environments". And one of the reasons for it is "what if you can't install packages into the global site-packages directory? For instance, on a shared host." You can't use it to install Python itself, but you already have a perfectly good Python, and you can use it for everything else. `py2app` has only worked properly with `virtualenv` since 0.7, and it may still have some bugs or limitations, but this is probably what I'd try first.

Comment: @tkbx: It _is_ definitely possible to install python itself somewhere under ~, and configure it so everything else gets installed there as well… but that might require compiling it, which you can't do. (I believe the binary installer can install to an external drive, if you have one of those around, or can buy one for $40, but not to an arbitrary path… but you may want to check that.)

Comment: okay, I created a 2.7.3 Python install in ~/bin/python with `virtual-python.py`. Now, is there a way to install py2app there without root?

Comment: Yes, every virtual environment comes with its own `pip`. This is all described in the Usage section in the docs, but the brief version is: Do `cd /path/to/virtualenv; source ./bin/activate`. Now your virtualenv is activated for the current terminal window, so you can just do `pip install py2app` in that window, and it uses the virtualenv's `pip`, so it installs into the virtualenv instead of system-wide, so you don't need to be root. You can also be explicit and do `/path/to/virtualenv/bin/pip`, but you shouldn't need to. Again, read the docs to understand everything.

Comment: I was using the wrong script to set up the environment (`virtual-python.py`, not `virtualenv.py`). Got it figured out not, thanks for the help.